# How to deal with with cookies, settings persistence

Tags: reactjs, go, cookies, session-cookies

[DEVELOPMENT] - All fine (no issues as cookies are set on same domain 'localhost')

[PROD / LIVE] - Link below

**The issue**: The cookie are not being set properly or not getting persisted, I don't know why so if anyone can give me an idea what might be the cause as you can see in network tab, it sets the cookie but it doesn't put it in `Application > Storage > Cookies` you can have a look if I am not explaining it very well.

https://gta-open-q99pjtak6-patricksubang.vercel.app/
username: demo
password: demo

Front end, POST/GET request

```js
const sendRequest = async (method, endpoint, custom) => {
  const isProd =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:8000/"
      : "https://gta-open.ga/";

  const url = isProd + endpoint;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    ...custom,
  });

  return response;
};
```

Setting session cookie using gorrilla\sessions

```golang
Cookie.Options.Path = "/"
Cookie.Options.HttpOnly = true
Cookie.Options.SameSite = http.SameSiteNoneMode
state := false
if os.Getenv("ENV") == "PROD" {
    state = true
}
Cookie.Options.Secure = state

func GenerateSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, uid int) (err error) {

    session, _ := Cookie.Get(r, "sessionid")
    session.Values["accountID"] = uid
    // Save it before we write to the response/return from the handler.
    err = session.Save(r, w)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    return
}
```

If anyone can give me a rough idea why, or the cause of the issue would be helpful

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with a Golang backend nor gorrilla sessions, but I'm pretty sure it's how you're configuring your cookie settings. Specifically, I believe the `domain` name being set to `gta-open.ga` doesn't match `vercel.app` so it's either being blocked by the browser's third party cookie settings or not being utilized because the domain names don't match.

For example, cookie blocked by 3rd party (user's browser preference):
[image]

As a result, no cookie is set:
[image]

However, if I allow 3rd party cookies from cross-domains, then the cookie is set:
[image]

However, since it has a different **domain** from the app, it's not being utilized:
[image]

---

On that note, I'd highly suggest purchasing your own domain. They're pretty cheap (10usd/7gbp or less per year), then you can set up your vercel app to use the [custom domain](https://vercel.com/docs/custom-domains). Then, set your cookie to use that custom domain name and it should be smooth sailing.

Otherwise, you'll have to set up the cookie to use subdomain's `.vercel.app` in production (which isn't recommended because vercel hosts a lot of apps on their subdomains) or use domain `gta-open-q99pjtak6-patricksubang.vercel.app`, but that's kind of silly.